# Regular Expression in R - regmatches

Tags: r, regex

could someone help me with the next regular expression?
I have to extract what it is in with_reg_expr

```
table=data.frame(col=c("1.8 20v 150cv turbo","1.6 8v 102cv","1.6 3-p","ro 35i 3.0 24v 306cv","polo 1.8 turbo"))

real_column           with_reg_expr
1.8 20v 150cv turbo   1.8 20v 150cv
1.6 8v 102cv          1.6 8v 102 cv
1.6 v8 102cv          1.6 v8 102 cv
1.6 3-p               1.6
ro 35i 3.0 24v 306cv  35i 3.0 24v 306cv
polo 1.8 turbo        1.8
```

I think about using those expressions

```
[0-9].[0-9]
{[0-9],2}v | v{[0-9],2}
{[0-9],3}cv
{[0-9],}i
```

with the function regmatches(table$col,regexpr("[0-9].[0-9]",table$col)).

Comment: Could you explain the patterns you wanted

Comment: Yes, first: number&point&number, second: two numbers & 'v' or 'v'&two numbers, third: tree numbers&'cv', four: any number(s)&'i'. (all in one only reg express)

Comment: Do you mean you also need to insert a space between number and `cv`? BTW, please test [this approach](http://ideone.com/5EyMxF).

Comment: I updated the link above, please check if the solution works as expected.

Comment: Excellent! I added as.data.frame(as.matrix(a),stringsAsFactors=F) to convert it in a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- c("1.8 20v 150cv turbo", "1.6 8v 102cv", "1.6 v8 102cv", "1.6 3-p", "ro 35i 3.0 24v 306cv", "polo 1.8 turbo")
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\bv?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:c?v?|i)(?!\\S)", x, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [R demo online](http://ideone.com/5EyMxF). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S9eVkm/1).

*Explanation*:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `v?` - an optional `v`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` followed with 1+ digits
- `(?:c?v?|i)` - either `i` or an optional `c` followed with an optional `v`
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead assertion requiring a whitespace or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "1.8"   "20v"   "150cv"

[[2]]
[1] "1.6"   "8v"    "102cv"

[[3]]
[1] "1.6"   "v8"    "102cv"

[[4]]
[1] "1.6"

[[5]]
[1] "35i"   "3.0"   "24v"   "306cv"

[[6]]
[1] "1.8"
```